# vb.net fastest way to match two long list and get which word is not found

Tags: vb.net, search

i have  "dictionary.txt" file in which it contains all dictionary words i am trying to syntax highlighting in richtextbox (vb.net)  of misspelled word

is there any way to check misspelled words in richtextbox by using dictionary.txt file

i am using for loop and checking each word but its taking too much time

```
Dim p As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To aryTextFile.Length - 1
        aryTextFile(i) = aryTextFile(i).Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "")

        If wordslistD.Contains(LCase(aryTextFile(i))) Then

        Else

            MisSpelledList.Add(aryTextFile(i))
        End If

            ProgressBar1.Value = p
            p = p + 1


    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try Except method? something like:

```
dim output = aryTextFile.Select(Function(x) x.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").ToUpper()).Except(wordsListD)
```

Comment: thank you very much its working super fine and very very fast

Comment: i am not good at string functions . is there any other string function which returns words near to the word for example if the search word is "th?" then it will suggest words near to word like "the,they" like ms word misspelled word suggestion

Comment: check regular expressions (Regex) and you could find a lot resources online

Comment: i google a lot about regex expression i found some good tutorial on it i have declare wordlist and add dictionary words in it. now how can i use regex expression to get multiple match words by passing single words thank you in advance

Comment: i tried this code    Dim matches = From c In wordslistD Where (c Like "the") Select c

        For Each w In matches
            MessageBox.Show(w)
        Next

Comment: did you mean auto-complete? if so, i think using "Like" should work